# Why did the EU give stronger "protections" to minors in the GDPR, considering that COPPA has had the effect of restricting those it tries to protect?

Tags: european-union, privacy, specific-legislation, gdpr

Quite a few years ago, the US passed COPPA, which imposes quite strict regulations on sites that collect information from children under 13. The end result was that many sites banned users under 13 years old. This isn't really that big of a problem; it could be argued that there are few sites not specifically designed for children that children this age have any reason to use.

When the European Union passed the GDPR, they included a provision that children cannot consent to data collection, and allowed member states to set the age of consent anywhere from 13 to 16. At least some picked 16. Why? Did they not expect the same thing that happened to children under 13 in the US with COPPA to happen to children and teens under 16 in the EU? The argument that most sites not specifically targeting children are not relevant to them is much weaker when "children" are defined as anyone under 16 rather than 13.

Did they somehow not expect this to happen, or did they determine that protecting the privacy of teens 13 to 15 is more important than their ability to use the Internet with few limitations?

Comment: Protecting people often involves restricting them.  Look at prison informants, they often get solitary confinement, not because they did anything wrong, but so they don't get killed for snitching.  Look at toddlers; we put them in playpens so they can't wander off and get themselves into dangerous situations.

Comment: @Ryan_L but is restricting teens from Web sites that are suitable for them except for the site's noncompliance with a privacy law much stricter than most people care about (I'm referring to the GDPR as it applies to children, not to adults; I think the GDPR as applied with adult users is overall reasonable) a reasonable way to protect them? The restriction is inability to use a sizable portion of the Internet that does not have content it's necessary to protect children from; the protection is against data collection that most people do not object to.

Comment: If parents object to the data collection, then they can make sure their child does not consent to data collection. If the child objects, they will not give consent. Only if the parent and child both agree that the tracking is okay, or if the child is okay with it and the parent does not care, will the child be tracked, if the GDPR treated everyone the same.

Comment: @Someone, children are legally minors *because* they cannot be expected to make reasoned/reasonable decisions for themselves. So any reasoning that involves them reading terms of service is missing the point.

Comment: @o.m. then why isn't the age of consent 18?

Comment: @Someone, there are different ages of consent for different things.

Comment: @o.m. that's my point; I'm asking why they picked 16 as the age of consent for data collection, when it causes very significant, seemingly unwarranted restrictions.

Comment: The title does not match the body & comments. And regarding *or did they determine that protecting the privacy of teens 13 to 15 is more important than their ability to use the Internet with few limitations?* Well, this principle was well established before (for example, with laws that prevented minors access to porn and gambling sites). Hardly surprising.

Comment: @SJuan76 sites with content inappropriate for minors are a small segment of the Internet. Sites that collect information and are not willing to comply with complicated parental consent requirements are a large portion of the Internet.

Comment: What is perhaps more surprising is that in 2022, anyone still believes that laws can prevent children from accessing whatever websites they want.

Comment: These kind of laws may impose additional regulatory burdens on companies, and change the data collection practices of those whose user base must perforce consist of many children, but I doubt that it will prevent any private citizen from doing absolutely anything.

Comment: The law isn't to stop minors from accessing anything, it's to encourage companies to not collect so much data on *everyone*, because it isn't cost-effective to *provably* restrict minors from the site.

Comment: GDPR itself is a disaster, this is just one more negative economic consequence of it.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Restrictions can be content-based rather than audience-based. Under US law, YouTube had to apply COPPA-like restrictions to any children's content on the website, regardless of whether the viewer is logged into a children's account or an adult's account (because, according to the FTC, some children have fake accounts, and therefore YouTube has to make a reasonable effort to apply COPPA to videos that those children are likely to watch, regardless of what account they use to watch said videos).

Comment: @Caleth with both COPPA and the child provisions of the GDPR, the intent was for sites to stop tracking children. In both cases, it's been very common for them to accomplish that by discriminating against those the law is meant to protect.

Answer (score 5):

The various EU members have slightly different national laws. Looking at [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), you will find different age limits

- for buying a donut, a beer, or a vodka,
- for buying something with immediate payment or in installments,
- for driving a motor scooter, a car, or a heavy motorcycle,
- for voting in municipal or federal elections (some states),
- for being liable for damages and being guilty of a crime.

While people can and do quibble about the exact placement of any one limit, the clear pattern is that younger children are more protected from decisions with grave consequences, **or with abstract consequences.** A minor may be allowed to buy something for €30, but not in 12 "easy" installments of €2.50 each.

The consequences of privacy loss can be abstract, until they happen.

Comment: *The consequences of privacy loss can be abstract, until they happen.* => would be good to elaborate what those "consequences" are supposed to be according to EU officials. Ideally in concrete rather than abstract terms.

Comment: @JonathanReez, depends on which site. Being googled by a prospective employer and the old drunken party selfies showing up. Being profiled. Early on I decided to use my initials and not my full name on this site ...

Comment: @JonathanReez: Juvenile criminal records are in many jurisdictions automatically sealed and sometimes also automatically expunged, because we assume that mistakes one makes as a kid should not necessarily define ones whole life. (A friend of mine was a prosecutor right out of law school and often remarked that he feels really bad prosecuting young adults for the exact same things he did just 10 years prior and which, had they been prosecuted, would have prevented him from becoming a prosecutor. He was an amazing prosecutor and is an amazing judge and law professor now, by the way.)

Comment: However, Facebook pictures of stupid things you do might live on forever, even though you might not hav understood at 13 years old what the consequences would be. They might prevent you from being hired, for example.

Comment: Is there an age limit for buying a donut in Germany? In the US, anyone could buy one as long as they had the money.

Comment: @Someone While a kid below the age of 7 *can* buy something, if it is more expensive than the kids allowance, the parents have the right to cancel that deal, give back whatever was bought and get the money back. While a single donut is probably below the actual allowance and not really refundable once eaten anyway, if the kid buys an expensive box of fancy donuts and not eats them immediately, the parents can give the box back and must get their money back, undoing their childs "contract" of buying them.

Comment: @nvoigt, are you sure you're not mixing below-7 and 7-to-14 here? A contract by a child below 7 is invalid ...